# Really basic about C++/Boost - testing boost

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I think I have boost installed properly so I am trying to use the test "first.cpp" found [here](http://tabreziqbal.wordpress.com/2006/03/16/how-to-test-c-boost-installation/):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/any.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::any a(5);
    a = 7.67;
    std::cout<<boost::any_cast<double>(a)<<std::endl;
}
```

And I get the following:

```
Jason@ITHAKA-DB44CFE1 /home/jason
$ g++ -o first first.cpp
first.cpp:2:24: boost/any.hpp: No such file or directory
first.cpp: In function `int main()':
first.cpp:6: error: `boost' has not been declared
first.cpp:6: error: `any' undeclared (first use this function)
first.cpp:6: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each
unction it appears in.)
first.cpp:6: error: expected `;' before "a"
first.cpp:7: error: `a' undeclared (first use this function)
first.cpp:8: error: `boost' has not been declared
first.cpp:8: error: `any_cast' undeclared (first use this function)
first.cpp:8: error: expected primary-expression before "double"
first.cpp:8: error: expected `;' before "double"
first.cpp:9:2: warning: no newline at end of file

Jason@ITHAKA-DB44CFE1 /home/jason
$
```

Where my boost library is in my ./home/Jason/

Obviously something is up. Also, all the boost libraries themselves use this "boost/..." so for some reason either:

1 - I did something wrong with Boost
2 - C++/gcc is not "seeing" my boost

any input?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `-I/home/Jason/include` to `gcc`, and probably a `-L/home/Jason/lib` too, because the library is not installed in the standard path. Try:

```
 g++ -I/home/Jason/include -L/home/Jason/lib -o first first.cpp
```

Also, once compiled, it will not run properly because the libraries are not in the standard path again. To run it, you need to add `/home/Jason/lib` to the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Edit: As Tony D pointed out, you can set `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` to `/home/Jason/include` instead, which is equivalent to the compiler option I gave you.

**Edit**

If you only want to test your install, you can run the `~/bin/Boost.Test` script (assuming you had `--with-libraries=test` enabled when you installed it). Otherwise there should be a `bin` directory in hour home (if you used that as prefix), if there is anything with the name `Boost` in it, try to run it (but remember to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before).

Comment: what is the "standard path"? I would rather just have it there.

Comment: Yes, you can leave it there, but then you need to tell GCC where to look for it.

Comment: how do i know if it is properly installed? is there anything i can do outside the above? how do i tell gcc where to look

Comment: by adding the flags i just told you

Comment: You can set `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` in your environment, adding the boost path (you want to include the versioned directory above "boost" as you'll be using `#include <boost/xxx>`).

Comment: This is making me think it did not install correctly. I ran bootstrap.cmd but I do not have the b2 directory mentioned here (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html). That being said I have not run the second command listed. Where should my .b2 be? Is this created by default?

Comment: At the same location as the bootstrap script you used to install boost. If you did not follow the other steps from this link, then yes, you probably didn't install it correctly.

Comment: I just came across this link (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/windows.html). Please treat this question as closed until I have a chance to complete this guide

Comment: That is a usage guide for windows users, I thought you were using Linux. Maybe this one http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html and even the full manual http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/index.html would be a good place to start.

Answer (score -1):

- header files link to '/usr/include'

`$ cd /usr/include` 
`$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/boost_xxxx/boost boost`

- compile boost library, and copy the so files to '/usr/lib'

`$ sudo cp /usr/local/lib/libboost_regex-gcc41-mt-xxxx.so.xxxx /usr/lib/`

Comment: I assume he installed it in his home directory because he couldn't do otherwise. But this would work, so would installing boost directly in the standard path ;)

Comment: @jasonm the standard path is where the compiler looks for system headers and libraries. This is where anything you install using the package manager will end up. It varies from system to system, but usually the main ones are `/usr` and `/usr/local`.

Comment: so i guess my concern here is really if i installed it properly. i ran the bootstrap.cmd and it seemed okay. is there anything else i need to do? really, i am not 100% convinced that I did this correctly. I am doing this to indeed check if it "installed" correctly.

Comment: i edited my reply, i didn't understand that you just wanted to test it.